# How to move all the type file file1.ext, .file2ext and .anotherext from folder to another folder with linux (debian) command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, debian, mv

I use the following command to move all files from one folder to another. In this case I move a file from folder1 to folder2 as the following command:

```
 # mv  -v /path2dir/subdir/folder1/* /var/www/folder2
```

Of course folder2 been made before.
The problem is not all the files moved successfully, some files like ***.file2ext*** , ***.anotherext*** or files starting with ***character (.)*** like ***.htaccess*** and ***.error_log*** not succeed on the move

how to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash offers a more flexible way to specify path tokens:

```
mv -v /path2dir/subdir/folder1/{.*,*} /var/www/folder2
```

Inside curly brackets you can specify a comma separated list of tokens. The shell will expend them by iterating over them, so handling all matches of all of them.

A shorter, but otherwise equivalent alternative is this:

```
mv -v /path2dir/subdir/folder1/{.,}* /var/www/folder2
```

Both alternatives will give you a warning about entries that will be skipped due to good reasons (`.` and `..`). You can suppress those by redirecting the error output of the command, but you should be careful with such thing, since you might miss important details that way:

```
mv -v /path2dir/subdir/folder1/{.,}* /var/www/folder2 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: ok, all files {. *, *} has moved ... thanks for your help :-)

Comment: if that fails, the file is still stored in folder1?

Comment: Files that cannot be moved will stay where they are, obviously. Might for example happen with files you do not have permissions to move. That is why I made the remark towards the end.

Comment: oh oke, I'm new :-) .. Thanks

Comment: All fine, we all started once :-) Have fun!